# Adding Neat, Bitters and Refills to a Hammer for Mac

Tags: macos, sass, bourbon, neat, hammer

I recently bought Hammer for Mac.

I am making a static site, and want to use Bourbon + Neat, Bitters and Refills to style the page.

If I am correct, Bourbon is already included in Hammer, but Neat, Bitters and Refills aren't?
At the Hammer for Mac homepage, it says the following about installing Neat:

"If you're using the fantastic Bourbon Neat framework with Hammer, you'll need to download the Neat code from the Neat GitHub repository. The SCSS files for Neat are located inside the app/assets/stylesheets directory.
To use Neat in your project, simply copy the contents of app/assets/stylesheets into a folder in your project. Then just use @import "neat"; in your SCSS or Sass files to use Neat."....

Which I did. I took it as the same needed to be done to include Bitters and Refills.

I then try to use the @import "neat"; commands in my main.scss, but the build always fail.

Any idea on how to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because Hammer for Mac uses a lower Sass version that's required to properly build Neat:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/issues/174

(In other words, download [Neat 1.5.1](https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/releases/tag/v1.5.1))